# Почему возникает ошибка в файле ejs

Tags: javascript

Возникает вот такая ошибка:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in /root/L3MON/assets/views/login.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (/root/L3MON/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:673:12)
    at Object.compile (/root/L3MON/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:398:16)
    at handleCache (/root/L3MON/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:235:18)
    at tryHandleCache (/root/L3MON/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:274:16)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (/root/L3MON/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (/root/L3MON/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/root/L3MON/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (/root/L3MON/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/root/L3MON/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
```

Вот мой код:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<%  include partials/head.ejs %>


<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #dbdbdb;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom right, #86fde8, #acb6e5);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #86fde8, #acb6e5);
        }

        body>.grid {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .image {
            margin-top: -100px;
        }

        .column {
            max-width: 450px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ui.form').form({
                fields: {
                    email: {
                        identifier: 'username',
                        rules: [
                            {
                                type: 'empty',
                                prompt: 'Please enter your username'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    password: {
                        identifier: 'password',
                        rules: [
                            {
                                type: 'empty',
                                prompt: 'Please enter your password'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div class="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">

        <div class="column">

            <form class="ui large form" method="POST">
                <div class="ui stacked segment">
                    <h2 class="ui image header">
                        <div class="content">
                            <img src="/logo.png" style="height: 70px;">
                        </div>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="ui left icon input">
                            <i class="user icon"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="ui left icon input">
                            <i class="lock icon"></i>
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Login</div>
                    <div class="ui error message"></div>

                </div>

            </form>
            <% include partials/footer.ejs %>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: Ну вроде как пишет же ошибку. Нет закрывающей скобки в функции после листа аргументов в файле вашем /root/L3MON/assets/views/login.ejs